# Native English Translations that capture the intended emotion of "그래야 비로소"

Tags: vocabulary, translation, phrase-meaning

Please provide some translations (not literal) that capture the true spirit of

> 그래야 비로소

[Google](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%EA%B7%B8%EB%9E%98%EC%95%BC%20%EB%B9%84%EB%A1%9C%EC%86%8C) translates it `That's it`.

[Daum's best](http://dic.daum.net/search.do?q=%EA%B7%B8%EB%9E%98%EC%95%BC%20%EB%B9%84%EB%A1%9C%EC%86%8C&dic=ee) combines the two for a very awkward `Only if one does that` + `not`.

I'm really interested in what someone with a good feel of both languages would offer as some options - with a phrase like this, there must be a dozen ways to say `No way jose` or `Not on your life` (*or are those two appropriate candidates?*)

Ah, and I suppose an example sentence is always helpful, eh?

> **그래야 비로소** 우리의 삶에 하나님이 원하시는 열매가 열리기 시작한다.

*Note: the suggested phrase does not have to "fit well" into the example sentence, but should capture the feeling well, even if the sentence's literal translation has to be significantly reworded - I'm trying to capture that emotion, not the literalism*

Comment: Incidentally, since this translation is due asap, I'm turning this version in as the translation for that sentence: `I mean, that's all there is to it, and only then will the fruit that God wants us to produce begin to appear.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the phrase `if only and only then finally` fits well.

> 무엇인가 해야 (하다 + 그래야) 비로소 무언가를 이룰 수 있다.

We must do something. If only and only then we can finally achieve something (we have been longing for).

Comment: nice! that's a good one

Comment: @Catomic has a good answer, too. i'm choosing this one since "if only" imbibes the 그래야 perhaps a smidgen better than "not till then", though i have given +1 to catomic for the *elevation emotion*; good stuff!

Answer (score 4):

As you say, I think the business of 'spirit capturing' is easier done for sentences than phrases.  How about:

> Not till then shall our lives begin to bear such fruit as shall please the Lord.

By itself '비로소' might have the feel of 'thenceforward' (in terms of elevation).

I am afraid 'that's all there is to it' (from your comments) would not do for two reasons.

- It emphasizes the sufficiency of the thing suggested (as if nothing *else* were needed). '비로소' however emphasizes the necessity of the thing.
- It is low register while '비로소' is high (even slightly archaic).